# Extend psycopg2 cursor class' __iter__ method

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am creating server-side cursors at several places during the course of a long ETL process. I want to automatically close the db connection once all rows are fetched from a server-side cursor.

Instead of doing that manually at every place the cursor is created, I want to define a custom `psycopg2` cursor class that closes the connection on exhausting iteration so that the client code(calling function) doesn't have to worry about open connections.

I tried the below but it's giving `RecursionError`. The statement `yield from super().__iter__()` works as expected when I tried extending other iterables, for e.g. `dict`.

```py
class AutoCloseCur(psycopg2.extensions.cursor):
    def __iter__(self):
        yield from super().__iter__()
        self.close()
        self.connection.close()
```

Am I extending the right `class`? Do I need to override any other dunder method?
Or does psycopg2 provide any function for achieving my goal?

Comment: Why not use [Context manager](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#with-statement). Look at the example in the **Warning** box.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver My code has two types of functions - first type which contains(or dynamically generates) a sql query and executes it, second that iterates over the sql result. The first type always returns a cursor object. The second type receives a cursor object. These two functions do not interact directly.  With `context manager` it's not possible to return or pass a cursor object.

Comment: You are concerned with the connection not the cursor.  The **Warning** example does not use a context manager and deals with closing the connection when an operation is finished, which is what you want.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I am concerned with both - _exhausting iteration on cursor should close the connection_. In my case, a function that receives the cursor object is going to treat it as an iterable without caring about closing the connection(or calling any other method on the cursor for that matter). Irrespective of whether this question is relevant for my use case or not, I am still interested in knowing how to override/extend cursor's `__iter__` method.

Comment: Take a look here [extras.py](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/master/lib/extras.py) at `class NamedTupleCursor` and its `def __iter__(self):`.  See if that helps.